# Adjacency list and the adjacency matrix for the directed cycle with 4 vertices and directed wheel with 5 vertices in total

Tags: graph-theory

I have encountered a problem while doing exercises in my text book.

The question is to **write down the Adjacency list and the adjacency matrix for the directed cycle with 4 vertices and directed wheel with 5 vertices in total**

If you could give me some help, it would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: This should be easy, *if* you know the definitions of those types of graph and of the adjacency matrix. Where do you have problems / what concept do you not understand?

Answer (score 4):

This is the directed cycle with $4$ vertices:

[image: Directed cycle with $4$ vertices]

This is the directed wheel with $5$ vertices in total:

[image: Directed wheel with $5$ vertices]

[I'm assuming the definition [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/WheelGraph.html).  There might be other definitions, but the process is still the same.]

To write down an adjacency list or adjacency matrix, we need to give the vertices labels.  The labels are arbitrary, but it's usually easier to choose labels such as $1,2,\ldots,n$.  So let's label the vertices as follows:

[image: Directed cycle with $4$ labelled vertices]

and

[image: Directed wheel with $5$ labelled vertices]

An [adjacency list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_list) is simply a list of the edges in the graph.  We can just read these from the above drawings:

- The adjacency list for directed cycle with $4$ vertices has adjacency list is $(1,2),(2,3),(3,4),(4,1)$.
- The adjacency list for directed wheel with $5$ vertices has adjacency list is $(1,2),(2,3),(3,4),(4,1),(5,1),(5,2),(5,3),(5,4)$.

*Note*: these are directed edges, so e.g. $(5,1)$ is different to $(1,5)$.

The [adjacency matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_matrix) of a directed graph $G$ is a $(0,1)$-matrix with a $1$ in cell $(i,j)$ whenever $(i,j)$ is an edge in $G$ (and $0$ otherwise).

- The adjacency matrix for directed cycle with $4$ vertices is

$$\begin{array}{|cccc|} \hline 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ \hline  \end{array}.$$

- The adjacency matrix for directed wheel with $5$ vertices is

$$\begin{array}{|ccccc|} \hline 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\ \hline \end{array}.$$

*One caveat*: the adjacency list and adjacency matrix will change depending on which way you label the vertices.